# change different weather in same scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, weather

In the same scene, there are over 1000 prefabs, unity how to change a different weather. changes like skybox 、lighting 、most important is change over 1000 prefabs material. like the clear weather material change to rain weather material.

Any good Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by having the `GameObjects` that you are going to modify in your controller like that:

```
public GameObject mySky;
public GameObject myLighting;
public GameObject myPrefab; 
// and so on
```

Then when the event is triggered and you want to change some of the states of there properties just get the component you are interested in like:

```
SomeComponent component = myPrefab.GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
```

and then modify the component itself. (It could be the skybox, the lighting and whatever else you need to access.

Comment: if do this ,i will find all the gameobjects in the scene to change material. It's not efficient.  but thanks for your replay.

Comment: @LAlex what do you mean by that you will only manage the gameobjects you put in the fields in the editor. The other way is to use tags and group them that way. They get gameobjets by tag.

Comment: lvan  i mean i don't want to change over 1000 prefabs's material. if like this ,may be can use two scene one of normal scene,one of rain scene.  and get gameobjects by tag is infeasible.  like item's tag .  the two items one inside and one outside.  so outside item need  change to rain material. inside not.             thanks your help.